# How to cook fried potatoes in a No Fry Cooker?

Tags: baking

I want to “No Fry” French fried potatoes. Can I stack them on top of each other to cook and brown a little? I have seen pictures of them being piled on top of each other in a No Fry Cooker. In a regular oven you put then on a sheet pan in one layer. Can they be piled on top of each other?

Answer (score 3):

The reason to spread out oven fries into a single layer is to remove moisture from them more effectively, so they don't end up soggy. An air fryer's convective heating is much more effective at removing moisture, even compared to a convection oven. So piling them up doesn't cause much of a problem. If your air fryer doesn't have a stirring arm, you should still stir or shake the fries partway through cooking, to ensure even browning and avoid soggy spots.